# amCharts, column with 2 y-axis

Tags: javascript, flash, amcharts

I am trying to create a bar chart with an extra Y-axis that maps the %-age of the bars.

This is the bar chart (works and shows the bars):

```
<settings>
    <colors>FFCC00</colors>
    <background>
        <alpha>100</alpha>
        <border_alpha>20</border_alpha>
    </background>
    <grid>
        <category>
            <dashed>1</dashed>
        </category>
        <value>
            <dashed>1</dashed>
        </value>
    </grid>
    <axes>
        <category>
            <width>1</width>
            <color>E7E7E7</color>
        </category>        
    </axes>
    <values>
        <category>
            <rotate>42</rotate>
        </category>
        <value>
            <min>0</min>
        </value>
    </values>
    <depth>15</depth>
    <column>
        <width>85</width>
        <balloon_text>{value} user(s)</balloon_text>
        <grow_time>3</grow_time>
    </column>
    <graphs>
        <graph gid="0">
            <title>Users</title>
            <color>3333CC</color>
            <alpha>63</alpha>
        </graph>
    </graphs>
    <labels>
        <label lid="0">
            <text><![CDATA[<b>User distribution</b>]]></text>
            <y>18</y>
            <text_color>000000</text_color>
            <text_size>13</text_size>
            <align>center</align>
        </label>
    </labels>
</settings>
```

Here is the data:

```
<chart>
    <series>
        <value xid="0">Afghanistan</value>
        <value xid="1">Andorra</value>
        <value xid="2">Australia</value>
        <value xid="3">Burundi</value>
        <value xid="4">China</value>
        <value xid="5">Denmark</value>        
    </series>
    <graphs>
        <graph gid="0">
            <value xid="0">7</value>
            <value xid="1">3</value>
            <value xid="2">2</value>
            <value xid="3">12</value>            
            <value xid="4">2</value>
            <value xid="5">6</value>            
        </graph>
    </graphs>
</chart>
```

What i want to do is this:
http://www.amcharts.com/line/two-y-axes-chart/

But i can't seem to be able to generate the second y-axis.
This y-axis should have 0% at the bottom and 100% at the top. Then i will provide the data of how many % the column x has. This should be drawn as a red line.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible with the current flash version. Javaversion required.